# How to partition effects of variables and interactions in a GAM?

Tags: r, interpretation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

**When using generalized additive models, can you partition the effects of variables and interactions?**

Here is an example:

```
library(mgcv)
library(gamair)
data("mpg", package = "gamair")
city <- gam(city.mpg ~ s(weight) + s(width) + ti(weight, width),
            data = mpg, method = "REML")
summary(city)
```

```
Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
city.mpg ~ s(weight) + s(width) + ti(weight, width)

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  25.8992     0.6518   39.73   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                   edf Ref.df      F p-value    
s(weight)        5.013  6.104 15.750  <2e-16 ***
s(width)         1.002  1.003  0.298   0.587    
ti(weight,width) 2.593  3.416  0.532   0.681    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.683   Deviance explained = 69.7%
-REML =  560.2  Scale est. = 13.55     n = 205
```

The summary reports that 69.7% of deviance is explained by the whole model. **Of this explained deviance, can we know how much is explained only by weight, only by width and only by the interaction of weight and width?**

**Are there ways to construct the models that improve our ability to partition effects?** In the `mgcv` package for example, I believe using `Z ~ s(A) + s(B) + ti(A,B)` is supposed to separate the effects more than using `Z ~ te(A,B)`.